# Update vs upgrade in French

Tags: traduction, informatique

When talking about a program in English, one can either [update or upgrade it](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13353/17712). How to make this distinction in French? I am only aware of "mettre à jour".

Answer (score 5):

"**Mettre à niveau**" (noun: *mise à niveau*) is the term used by the French translations of Windows or Ubuntu when they release a new version of their OS. I agree it is not often heard, but it is the correct translation.

As Begueradj said, "**mettre à jour**" is often used for both *update* and *upgrade* here in France, at least in speech. Iliagre's answer mentioned "effectuer une montée de version" : I must warn you that it is super formal, and if I had read it somewhere I would have thought it was a Google translation :)

You could say "**passer à la nouvelle version / à la version suivante**". It is a bit more colloquial but you can hear it everyday.

Answer (score 4):

While ***mettre à jour*** is often used for both "update" and "upgrade", the latter might be more precisely translated by *mettre à niveau* (rarer) or *effectuer une **montée de version*** (clearer).

Note that the difference between "update" and "upgrade" is sometimes fuzzy and might be more dictated by marketing reasons than actual underlying code versioning scheme, i.e. a new major version (-> upgrade) might just cover slight changes while a new minor version (-> update) might bring new functionalities and even incompatible changes.

---

Edit: I don't get why some comment writers and downvoters have an issue with ***montée de version***. Here are some random links showing this well known expression used in French documents and so not being a google translate artifact:

*identifier les processus métiers spécifiques impactés par la **montée de version***
http://codilog.fr/offres/solutions/montee-de-version-upgrade.html

*ERP : bénéfices et pièges croisés de la **montée de version***
http://www.journaldunet.com/solutions/0612/061201-erp-montee-version.shtml

*Présentation de l’offre **Montée de version SAP***
http://www.hrc-consulting.fr/expertise-conseil/erp-sap/montee-de-version

*Votre système d'information a désespérément besoin de nouvelles fonctionnalités mais vous craignez la complexité des **montées de version** ?*
http://www.axiossystems.fr/fr/solutions/upgrade.html

*Je bosse sur un projet open-source depuis un petit moment et pour le moment **les montées de versions** ce font à chque fois fromscratch. (sic)*
http://linuxfr.org/forums/programmationautre/posts/methode-pour-gerer-les-montees-de-version-de-structure-de-base-de-donnees

*En général il est bon d'attendre 3/4 mois avant de prendre une décision pour **la montée de version Windows**.* 
http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=298569&sid=372c07fa5951ab37ef490b1fc72a5bd8#298569

*Vous êtes également amené à préconiser des démarches de rationalisation du parc ainsi qu’à planifier **la montée de version des systèmes** (en tenant compte des contraintes ‘éditeur’ le cas échéant).*
http://www.alcyane.com/en/nous-rejoindre/job/67-h-f-administrateur-systeme-windows-server---expertise-citrix-et-vmware.html

Comment: Never heard montée de version and I must disagree with its 'clearer' adjective.

Comment: @JeromeJ You are free to disagree. Like all jargon expression, there might be niches where it is unknown and others where it is well known. No problem.

Comment: Could it be you were referencing some colloquial way of saying it VS official/usual actual writing/display in a software? I might be making an extraneous interpretation out of your answer but it left me curious, my knowledge may indeed be limited. Just shared my experience, thanks for your thoughtful answer.

Comment: I'm a french software developer. I've never seen "montée de version" and you have inversed your definitions. major version = new functionalities / minor version = small changes

Comment: I'm a French software developer too and have heard _montée de version_ more often than _mise à niveau_, though it was often used to qualify the delivery of our own products on the production servers. It is indeed not used (AFAIK) for the public, only between developers/IT guys.

Comment: @StephaneMathis You missed my point. I am not confusing the definitions. I'm precisely telling major/minor versioning might, in some cases, be dictated by non technical reasons and be reversed from the expected logic.

Answer (score 3):

I am working in the computer science field:  for both verbs (update/upgrade) we use the same (and the only) expression: ***mettre à jour***.

Note that in the past, French computer science literature was used to recommend the use of ***mettre à jour*** for update and ***mettre à niveau*** for upgrade. However, this is no longer the case as ***mettre à jour*** is always and widely used for both verbs whereas ***mettre à niveau*** tends  to disappear.

No one uses in daily life practice/literature any of the other equivalent expressions mentioned [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_%C3%A0_niveau).

Comment: Google Ngram doesn't support the idea "mettre à niveau" tends do disappear. On the opposite its usage, while definitely lagging behind "mettre à jour" is steadily increasing. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mettre+%C3%A0+niveau%2Cmettre+%C3%A0+jour&year_start=1950&year_end=2015&corpus=19&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmettre%20%C3%A0%20niveau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmettre%20%C3%A0%20jour%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Actually the link you provided is a proof for what I stated, look to the huge difference of  their usage :) Also, I read the post he linked to (related to the use of upgrade/update in the world of computer science, where we do not use *mettre à niveau* at all). I may say *mettre à niveau* could be used in other fields: athletism, sports ... Regards @jlliagre

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing ranks and trends. I'm not questioning the fact "mettre à jour" is more widely used. I just disagree with the statement about "mettre à niveau" disappearing. "Mettre à niveau" is definitely also used in computer science and more there than in other areas. I am working in the CS industry too and both use it or hear it from colleagues and customers so I disagree about your statement about that expression not being used at all in the world of CS. I tend to prefer "montée de version" though when I need to make clear it is not a simple update but an upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

- **Updating:** *Mise(s) à jour disponible(s)*, **verb:** *Mettre à jour*.
- **Upgrading:** *Nouvelle version disponible*, **verb:** *Passer à la nouvelle version / Mettre à jour*.

**EDIT:** I didn't see the others suggest **mise à niveau** (from *mettre à niveau*), which is still somewhat rare.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux termes tournent autour du même thème: changer pour améliorer quelque chose, ou aller vers quelque chose de nouveau, **mais ne sont pas interchangeables.**

**Update**

Mettre à jour pour un **logiciel**, une configuration, des paramètres, notamment pour le rendre compatible avec d'autres, pour corriger des défauts, pour avoir des fonctions plus récentes, plus performantes.

Il y a une notion temporelle: la version est plus récente, et on considère qu'il n'y en a qu'il n'y en a qu'une la plus à jour à un instant donné (les anciennes font l'objet éventuel d'une maintenance).

Cela n'a à priori aucun sens de revenir vers une version antérieure *considérée comme moins bonne*.

Le terme update est moins employé pour les matériels, qui font plutôt l'objet d'une maintenance, et de remplacements -, sauf pour leur partie logicielle, puisqu'il en existe très souvent (driver/pilot, microcode)

Traduction française affreuse: updater (prononcer eupdater).

Le terme **Downdate** n'existe pas.

**Upgrade**

Mettre à niveau (vers le haut), *en montant de version.*

Monter de gamme, augmenter la capacité matérielle, la puissance.

Cela concerne aussi bien les logiciels que les matériels.

Il n'y a pas de notion temporelle. Les différentes versions peuvent coexister au même instant.

**On utilise aussi : Downgrade , pour revenir à une version plus faible (qui peut être ou non antérieure), plus légère, moins coûteuse.**

Traduction française affreuse: upgrader (prononcer eupgrader).

Quand on rencontre des problèmes de compatibilité, et qu'on ne peut pas updater ou upgrader, on downgrade.

Mise à jour / Mise à niveau

La même distinction peut se trouver en ce qui concerne des connaissances (professionnelles, académiques, ...):

- mise à jour: revoir ses connaissances, par rapport à ce qui a changé;
- mise à niveau (mais souvent employé comme le précédent): acquérir des connaissances supérieures.

Dans le même genre de traduction directe, on trouve:

- **downsizer** (prononcer daönsailleser), **downloader**, **uploader**, ...
- scalable, scalabilité