# Need a translation into Canadian French

Tags: traduction, québec

I've generated the following translations for these two sentences, but they don't quite sound right to me. I'd like some feedback!

After the pink progress bar disappears, you must restart the device to complete the upgrade. = Une fois que la barre de progression rose disparaît, redémarrez l'appareil pour terminer la mise à niveau.

The process may take several minutes. = Le processus peut prendre quelques minutes.

Please advise! I don't want the text to sound too robotic or formal. How would this sound in conversational Canadian French?

Comment: Quebecer reporting in. Both of these sound fine to me.

Comment: several = plusieurs (**not** quelques)

Comment: @Feelew I wouldn't reject *quelques* which looks to me as good as *plusieurs* here.

Comment: @jlliagre, Here is the time to transmit the very useful information _Volée de chênes et rosiers_ indicated to me just a few days ago about [**plusieurs**](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2886) in France and _New France_. Cheers mate!

Comment: @Feelew Interesting thanks. The OQLF also [states](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1570) `Le déterminant pluriel quelques signifie « plusieurs, un petit nombre de, un certain nombre de »` so should still properly translate "several" unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @jlliagre Generally in Quebec _plusieurs_ is more than _quelques_. _«Plusieurs personnes à la réunion»_ is rather positive. _«Quelques personnes à la réunion»_ neutral or slightly disappointed. The only point where I could see the two words being just about equivalent would be with tiny things, like snowflakes, sand grains, mosquitoes: _«qq/plusieurs flocons sont tombés»_ or _«il a laissé qq/plusieurs grains de sable sur le plancher» are just about equivalent.

Comment: @jlliagre My last comment was made early in the morning, when my thoughts were not quite as clear as I now wish they had been. Basically, while **plusieurs** does have common grounds with both **quelques** and **several**, these last two do not overlap. _Several_ is on the _‘beaucoup’_ end of _plusieurs_, while _quelques_ is rather on the _‘un peu’_ end. Sorry for being muddy in my previous comment.

Comment: @Feelew Thanks. My issue is probably more with correctly understanding "several" than with *quelques/plusieurs*. In France French, both *quelques* and *plusieurs* span the same range of numbers (between two or three and not much more than ten, more than that would be *une dizaine, quelques dizaines, …*). *Quelques* means the actual value is likely to be the lower range while *plusieurs* means the actual value can be anywhere in the range. They definitely overlap here.

Comment: @jlliagre Indeed re: "several" — I'd say that whatever the denotation, the connotation of "several" is influenced by its *not* being the alternative: "a few"!

Answer (score 3):

The *une fois* structure doesn't work quite like "once" in English.

> **Une fois la barre de progression rose disparue,** redémarrez l'appareil pour terminer la mise à niveau.

As Feelew writes, *quelques* could be replaced by *plusieurs*. (I think *quelques* connotes that it'll be "only a few", whereas the English usually reads like an invitation to go make yourself a cup of tea.)

> Le processus peut prendre **plusieurs** minutes.

You can also trade the "can" of *peut* for the "could" of *pourrait*, though both seem okay to me here.

> Le processus **pourrait** prendre plusieurs minutes.

Those are my suggestions. I'm open to anyone else's if they want to comment them.

*Edit*: Also, noting the comments below, if you give some extra context as to what sort of upgrade it is, we can help decide if the various terms are perfectly right (type of process, significance of upgrade...).

Comment: I believe the conditional might sound better, for a reason I cannot quite pinpoint. Also, while I process my data at the end of the day on an English job, je _traite mes données_ on a French job... «Le traitement pourrait prendre plusieurs minutes» could be considered.

Comment: @Feelew But this is not about data analysis. I's clearly about some sort of software update. "traitement" has no business anywhere near this translation. On the other end, it should be *mise à **jour***, not *mise à niveau*.

Comment: @Circeus "Upgrade" can be translated by *mise à niveau* and "update" by *mise à jour* although the latter might be used for both. This topic has been discussed and not everyone agreed. See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16254/update-vs-upgrade-in-french

Comment: True. I'm guilty of not having put together the two sentences. It is indeed about updates, and not about treating data. I just found _processus_ quite vague and thought it could be _processed_ as a unit. My mistake.